# Laravel Undefined index Error in array values display

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4.2. I have two mysql tables OwnTable, OtherTable. I am getting values successfully from these tables through php.

My further PHP code look like below to display values in blade php,

```
if (!empty ($OwnTable)){
            foreach($OwnTable as $owntbl){
                $Finalvalue['OwnValue']['Name'] = $owntbl->Name;
            }
        }
if (!empty ($OtherTable)){
            foreach($OtherTable as $othertbl){
                $Finalvalue['OtherValue']['Name'] = $othertbl->Name;
            }
        }

 $myData = array('Finalvalue' => $Finalvalue);
 if(.....) {
    return View::make('display')->with('myData', $myData);
 }
```

And the code in display.blade look like below,

```
            <tbody>     
                @foreach($myData['Finalvalue'] as $res)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{{$res['OwnValue']['Name']}}}</td>
                        <td>{{{$res['OtherValue']['Name']}}}</td>
                     </tr>
                @endforeach     
            </tbody>
```

When I try to run the code, it gives an error 'Undefined index: OwnValue'.

I am sure I am doing some mistakes in array Handling. I am not so much talent in array handling. Highly appreciate if anyone suggest me in this. Thanks :-)

Comment: For what reason I get vote down now? It is exactly the business logic what my clients wanted and the code is exists. I just have to display in right manner. Even I wrote I am new ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, use `var_dump` to debug and see how your arrays look like at different places within your code. For example you can see what does `$res` look like inside the foreach loop in the view and see why you have any undefined indices.

Overall your code looks a little more complicated than it should be, but I will put that on a side. Uou are setting different values to the same key, add empty brackets to indicated that you are going to push new values to the array:

```
foreach($OwnTable as $owntbl){
    $Finalvalue['OwnValue']['Name'][] = $owntbl->Name;
}
```

You can even use your old keys (if they matter):

```
foreach($OwnTable as $key => $owntbl){
    $Finalvalue['OwnValue']['Name'][$key] = $owntbl->Name;
}
```

Note that Blade needs only two pairs of curly brackets in the view (currently you have 3 pairs).

So yeah, track down the state of your arrays by using `var_dump` and find where things go wrong.